# Count occurrences of a specific value in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, counting

Let's say I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
[
    ["Thing1", "OtherThing1"],
    ["Thing1", "OtherThing2"],
    ["Thing2", "OtherThing3"]
]
```

How would I be able to count how many times the value "Thing1" occurs in the multidimensional array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$arr =array(
array("Thing1","OtherThing1"),
array("Thing1","OtherThing2"),
array("Thing2","OtherThing3")
);

echo "<pre>";
$res  = array_count_values(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr));

echo $res['Thing1'];
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [Thing1] => 2
    [OtherThing1] => 1
    [OtherThing2] => 1
    [Thing2] => 1
    [OtherThing3] => 1
)
```

It gives the occurrence of each value. ie : `Thing1` occurs `2` times.

**EDIT** : As per OP's comment : "Which array do you mean resulting array?" - The input array. So for example this would be the input array: array(array(1,1),array(2,1),array(3,2)) , I only want it to count the first values (1,2,3) not the second values (1,1,2) – gdscei 7 mins ago

```
$arr =array(
array("Thing1","OtherThing1"),
array("Thing1","OtherThing2"),
array("Thing2","OtherThing3")
);

$res  = array_count_values(array_map(function($a){return $a[0];}, $arr));

echo $res['Thing1'];
```

Comment: +1 for use array functions directly but i have one question how to get particular "thing1" count using this answer only.

Comment: $answers=array_count_values(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr)); echo $answers['Thing1']

Comment: the array_count_values works, but what if the first and second value in the array are the same? I don't want the 2nd value to count.

Comment: @gdscei : "what if the first and second value in the **array** are the same?" - which array do you mean resulting array ?

Comment: In resulting array it shows the occurance of a particular value, if value occurs two times, Eg: in question `Thing1` occurs 2 times so resulting array shows `$res['Thing1']` as `2`

Comment: "Which array do you mean resulting array?" - The input array. So for example this would be the input array: `array(array(1,1),array(2,1),array(3,2))` , I only want it to count the first values (1,2,3) not the second values (1,1,2)

Comment: @gdscei : Edited the answer please check it now :)

Comment: By putting the function out of the `array_map`, and referring it there then, it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can use `array_search` for more information see this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

this code is sample of this that is in php document sample

```
<?php 
function recursiveArraySearchAll($haystack, $needle, $index = null) 
{ 
 $aIt     = new RecursiveArrayIterator($haystack); 
 $it    = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($aIt); 
 $resultkeys; 

 while($it->valid()) {        
 if (((isset($index) AND ($it->key() == $index)) OR (!isset($index))) AND (strpos($it->current(), $needle)!==false)) { //$it->current() == $needle 
 $resultkeys[]=$aIt->key(); //return $aIt->key(); 
 } 

 $it->next(); 
 } 
 return $resultkeys;  // return all finding in an array 

} ; 
?>
```

If needle is found in haystack more than once, the first matching key is returned. To return the keys for all matching values, use `array_keys()` with the optional search_value parameter instead.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: searches for and returns key (not keyS)

Comment: @Waygood If needle is found in haystack more than once, the first matching key is returned. To return the keys for all matching values, use array_keys() with the optional search_value parameter instead.

Comment: I did read it. You need to use `array_keys()` NOT `array_search()`

Comment: No Probs,I'd already +1'd your answer anyway for 'walking' through the array

Answer (score 2):

```
function showCount($arr, $needle, $count=0)
{
    // Check if $arr is array. Thx to Waygood
    if(!is_array($arr)) return false;

    foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
    {
        // if item is array do recursion
        if(is_array($v))
        {
            $count = showCount($v, $needle, $count);
        }
        elseif($v == $needle){
            $count++;
        }
    }
    return $count;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `in_array` can help:

```
$cont = 0;

//for each array inside the multidimensional one
foreach($multidimensional as $m){
    if(in_array('Thing1', $m)){
        $cont++;
    }
}

echo $cont;
```

For more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: did you check output?...it's not working...have to use $cont++

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$arr =array(
array("Thing1","OtherThing1"),
 array("Thing1","OtherThing2"),
 array("Thing2","OtherThing3")
 );
   $abc=array_count_values(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr));
  echo $abc[Thing1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 0;

foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
if(in_array("Thing1", $value)) $count++;
}
```

Comment: multi-dimension! use array_walk_recursive or array_map

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer code brevity zero global scope pollution, you can count every value and access the one count that you do want:

```
echo array_count_values(array_merge(...$array))['Thing1'] ?? 0;
```

---

If you don't want to bother counting values where the count will never be needed, then you can visit leafnodes with `array_walk_recursive()` and +1 everytime the target value is encountered.

```
$thing1Count = 0;
array_walk_recursive($array, function($v) use(&$thing1Count) { $thing1Count += ($v === 'Thing1'); });
echo $thing1Count;
```

Both snippets return `2`.  Here's a [Demo](https://3v4l.org/0DYqj).